# Spring image URL is not resolved in ipad

Tags: image, ipad, spring, url, mobile-safari

I'm using spring tiles framework to display the screens where I have mentioned spring url for image path by giving like ${baseurl}.

It is working fine in both Mozilla and safari browsers desktop.when I try to access the application by ipad browser(safari)there i'm not able to see my image getting loaded.

Please help me on this.

Comment: It would be easier if you posted some relevant code from your view.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that the browser affect the way tiles work.

I can imagine that the way you referere to an image url in you jsp is wrong. The recomended way is somethink like that:

```
 <c:url value="/imagefolder/myimage.png" var="imgUrl" />
 <img src="${imgUrl}" width="64" height="64" />
```